# Ubuntu-Fedora dual-boot: Set up swap partitions for simultaneous hibernation?

Tags: dual-boot, swap, fedora

I want to install another Linux distribution (Fedora) besides Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. As I like to hibernate my system and as I want to use this feature on both installed Linux distributions, how many swap partitions do I need? And if I need multiple swap partitions, how do I configure them?

Edit/Clarification: I want to be able to hibernate both operating systems simultaneously. I assume that I need a separate swap partition for each installation (correct?), so how do I assign a specific swap partition to each of the installations, avoiding that one of my installations uses the wrong swap partition? Is it enough to list only the assigned swap partition in an installation's `/etc/fstab`? Or what else do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use shared swap AND hibernate.  They need separate swap partitions.

If you decide to use shared swap and find that one is trying to resume from a non-hibernating swap (the issue I think is probably at hand) you may be able to edit the kernel boot parameters to include ["noresume"](http://oreilly.com/linux/excerpts/9780596100797/kernel-boot-command-line-parameter-reference.html) to keep it from trying to restore from swap.

Yes, putting the correct swap partition in /etc/fstab should be enough.

Note that this is untested, but it should work.  If it doesn't, let me know and I'll delete it.  If it does, then great.

Answer (score -2):

Nope, you don't need multiple partitions. But you won't be able to hibernate both of them simultaneously (assuming Fedora also uses swap space to dump the contents while hibernating).

So, if you hibernate Ubuntu and run Fedora, you shouldn't hibernate Fedora, and vice-versa.